# Finding a loop within a Grid (Java)

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array, grid, coordinates

I am currently working on a problem in which I have a 2D List of Characters with n rows and m columns. Said Characters in the list are either 'N', 'S', 'E', or 'W' representing the 4 coordinates.

For example, a 2D list of 4 rows and 5 columns could be represented as `List<List<Character>> grid =` :

```
SESWE
EESNW
NWEEN
EWSEN
```

In this problem, I also have a starting position within the grid (always somewhere on the edge). For example, in this problem my starting position would be (0,0).

The problem that I am having to solve is that I must following the directions through the grid and identify where a loop occurs, how many instructions come before the loop, and how many instructions the loop has. To follow the directions through the grid, you simply follow whatever coordinate you are at in the grid. For example, (0,0) is S or South, so you go down one element to (1, 0) which is E or East. From there you go east one coordinate to (1,1) which is another E or East. So on and so forth.

For this particular grid, if you follow the coordinates from (0,0), the path through the grid should look like the following:

[image]

In this grid, the loop itself has 8 instructions, and there are 3 instructions before the loop.

I am having a hard time coming up with an algorithm that can accomplish this goal. I thought at first that I should first follow the path through the grid and leave a little breadcrumb behind at each element that I have visited so that if I visit it again I know that I am in the loop. So in this case it would look like this after I have visited all of the elements:

```
. E . . E
. . . . .
N W . . .
E W S E N
```

I accomplished this with the following:

```
while (gridCopy.get(curRow).get(curCol) != '.') {
            if (gridCopy.get(curRow).get(curCol) != '.') {
                if (gridCopy.get(curRow).get(curCol) == 'N') {
                    gridCopy.get(curRow).set(curCol, '.');
                    curRow--;
                } else if (gridCopy.get(curRow).get(curCol) == 'S') {
                    gridCopy.get(curRow).set(curCol, '.');
                    curRow++;
                } else if (gridCopy.get(curRow).get(curCol) == 'W') {
                    gridCopy.get(curRow).set(curCol, '.');
                    curCol--;
                } else if (gridCopy.get(curRow).get(curCol) == 'E') {
                    gridCopy.get(curRow).set(curCol, '.');
                    curCol++;
                }
            }
        }
```

All this does, though, is tell me that I do in fact have a loop in the grid and doesnt tell me how many instructions the loop is and how many instructions are before the loop.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction on this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible implementation. Basically you store the coordinates you've traversed in a list and if the coordinate is already in that list then you've found a loop. I didn't add code to check if the search goes out of bounds so I'm assuming that all the grids are well behaved and that they all have at least one loop. Anyhow below is the code with more explanations as comments:

```
// Class to store the coordinates
public static class Coordinate {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Coordinate(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Coordinate that = (Coordinate) o;

        if (x != that.x) return false;
        return y == that.y;
    }
}
```

Loop finder:

```
public static void loopFinder(List<List<Character>> grid, int startingX, int startingY) {
    // Not checking if one went outside of the grid

    // Store the coordinates we've traversed, if we find a duplicate then there's a loop
    List<Coordinate> traversedCoordinates = new ArrayList<>();
    Coordinate currentCoordinate = new Coordinate(startingX, startingY);
    traversedCoordinates.add(currentCoordinate);

    while (true) {
        char direction = grid.get(currentCoordinate.getY()).get(currentCoordinate.getX());
        switch (direction){
            case 'N':
                currentCoordinate = new Coordinate(currentCoordinate.getX(), currentCoordinate.getY() - 1);
                break;
            case 'E':
                currentCoordinate = new Coordinate(currentCoordinate.getX() + 1, currentCoordinate.getY());
                break;
            case 'S':
                currentCoordinate = new Coordinate(currentCoordinate.getX(), currentCoordinate.getY() + 1);
                break;
            case 'W':
                currentCoordinate = new Coordinate(currentCoordinate.getX() - 1, currentCoordinate.getY());
                break;
        }
        if(traversedCoordinates.contains(currentCoordinate)) {
            // found a loop
            traversedCoordinates.add(currentCoordinate);
            break;
        }
        traversedCoordinates.add(currentCoordinate);
    }

    // find index of current coordinate that will give us how many instructions before the loop started
    int numOfInstructionsBefore = traversedCoordinates.indexOf(currentCoordinate);
    int lengthOfLoop = traversedCoordinates.size() - numOfInstructionsBefore - 1;

    // I don't know if you need to include the starting and ending point of the loop
    // in that case you might have to offset the two values above.
    System.out.println("Number of instruction before the loop: " + numOfInstructionsBefore);
    System.out.println("Length of the loop: " + lengthOfLoop);
}
```

Usage:

```
public static void  main(String[] args) {

    List<List<Character>> grid = new ArrayList<>();
    grid.add(List.of('S', 'E', 'S', 'W', 'E'));
    grid.add(List.of('E', 'E', 'S', 'N', 'W'));
    grid.add(List.of('N', 'W', 'E', 'E', 'N'));
    grid.add(List.of('E', 'W', 'S', 'E', 'N'));

    loopFinder(grid, 0, 0);
}
```

Output:

```
Number of instruction before the loop: 3
Length of the loop: 8
```

Comment: perfect. thank you so much

Comment: @ParkerHarrelson123 glad I could help. I made an update after I re-read the question and realized that the starting point of the loop doesn't have to be counted twice so I added a `-1` to make the total number of instructions in the loop 8 instead of 9.